# Error while deploying flutter application on google play store

Tags: flutter, google-play

When deploying a flutter application on Google Play Store the following warning message appears:

Warning

This App Bundle contains native code, and you haven't imported any debugging symbols. We recommend importing a symbol file to help analyze and debug crashes and ANR errors.

Answer (score 0):

That is something coming from the Flutter codebase itself. Its been like that for a long time now and hope the future releases resolve that.

For now, you can simply ignore the warning and proceed with publishing the app.